# How do you programmatically - or from CLI - rotate a PDF?

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript, suse

What I need to be able to do is to rotate a PDF clockwise or counter clockwise either programmatically or from the CLI.

I have spent considerable time researching and attempting to rotate PDFs with GhostScript (as GS is already installed for other reasons) to no avail, nothing seems result in any rotation.

I have looked into using pdftk but it requires java libraries, and I would rather not have java installed on the system.

We've even looked at modifying the PDF file ourselves, and we have had some success with this, but we haven't come across a reliable method that works for all PDFs.

So my #1 preference would be to achieve this with existing resources on the system.
My #2 preference would be to do a little modification to the existing system as possible to achieve this.

The server in question is using Linux (OpenSuse 11) with PHP 5.2 and I have Ghostscript 9.0 installed.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **pdfpages** LaTeX package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[angle=45]{document.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The LaTeX document above, compiled via pdflatex, produces a document rotated 45 degrees.

There are also tools (wrappers of pdfpages) like **pdfjam** that can be used directly from command line:

```
$ pdfjam --suffix rotated45 --angle 45 --fitpaper true document.pdf
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting all of the dependancies lined up to try this.  Is there a good repository I could point yast at to install this?

Comment: I used `zypper in texlive-latex` to install latex, and then installed an RPM for pdfjam.  This is rotating the PDFs from the CLI now.  Thanks!

Comment: To install pdfjam on Ubuntu/Debain-based Linux, run `sudo apt-get install texlive-extra-utils`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), if that's available to you.

Example:

`$ convert originalfile.pdf -rotate <cw_angle_degrees> newfile.pdf`

Note, however, that since this is a raster-based rotation, there will (generally) be a noticeable loss of quality AND increase in filesize.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, ImageMagick is installed in this application.  However, I did want to avoid a rasterized rotation.

Comment: That does work by the way.  But unfortunately the quality is simply unusable.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you are trying to do this with Ghostscript, but if you want to use the pdfwrite device you will need to set /AutoRotatePages=/None or it will rotate the final page so that the majorty of any real text is horizontal.

Comment: I didn't want to go into all of the permutations that didn't work, I was hoping someone who has actually seen GS rotate a PDF would chime in.  But here is one of many attempts that didn't achieve anything:`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="/tmp/output.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dAutoRotatePages=/None -c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice " -f  "/tmp/input.pdf"`

Comment: Also tried: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="/tmp/output.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dAutoRotatePages=/None -c "90 rotate setpagedevice " -f  "/tmp/input.pdf"`  As well as: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="/tmp/output.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dAutoRotatePages=/None -c "90 rotate" -f  "/tmp/input.pdf"`  ...to name a couple more.

Comment: /Orientation refers to the orientation of the media, not the marks on the page. You would need to rotate the Current Transform Matrix instead. <</Install {90 rotate}>> setpagedevice might work though I haven't tried it. Obviously I'd need a sample file to test it.

Comment: No dice with the `<</Install {90 rotate}>> setpagedevice`.  As far as a sample goes...  There are loads and loads of PDFs available all over, any of them should provide a good sample to work with.  Just do a google search for: `filetype:PDF`  :)  In fact here's a good one to work with: `http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1607.pdf`

Comment: I really want one that you specifically have a problem with. I can try the one you mention.